# How to check whether sent E-mail is delivered or not?

Tags: email

A few days ago, I sent an email to a party but they did not reply me and I cannot call them to confirm whether my mail was delivered or read by them. I am in a very high pressure situation, so I want to know whether my email is being delivered or not.

- I sent an email from Gmail.
- I sent an email from Mozilla Firefox browser.
- I use Windows 10.
- Their email address is like abc@company.com.
- I sent attachments along with my email.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "You can't".

The basic email protocol does not have any mechanism which requires acknowledgement of receipt built in to it, and once the email has left you, its no longer in your control, and (rightly imho), you do not get to dictate what can be done with it.

There are a few things which can be done which can confirm if an email has been read - however there is no requirement that the recipient do these things, so its a matter of "if they do these things you can confirm they have read it, but if they don't confirm, it does not mean they have not read it".   These also require preparation BEFORE the email is sent, so won't help you unless you send another email (or did them before hand).

The first thing you can do is specify a "read receipt" request.  When an email is opened it can send a notification to the sender confirming it has been read.  Most applications will, however, prompt the recipient before sending t he confirmation.   This mechanism uses the browser.

The alternative mechanism requires crafting an email with images (often, but not always a 1x1 clear pixel), with a unique name hosted on a web server.  If and when the mail client opens the image, the web server can track that the image has been sent. This mechanism is often used by mailing lists - and, of-course, mail clients can be configured not to open off-site images or 1x1 images etc.

Comment: SMTP has had delivery status notifications [since 1996](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1891). Sadly many servers still don't support it...

Comment: Largely agreed,  RFC1894  this works at an MTA level and does not prove the user has opened it - in fact all references to user agents in the RFC talk about "allow", rather then "require".    Section 4 (particularly 4) make this optional - and indeed, any provider who sends notifications for their client is breaching confidence (ie is illegal in some countries), and opening up their clients to spam.  [ FWIW, I think its a GOOD thing that servers don't support it ]

Comment: Hmm, where is delivery status illegal? Many post offices have certified/registered mail as an equivalent... (Read receipts are another thing of course. I'm not talking about those.)

Comment: I live in New Zealand, and I would be extremely hesitant to allow this behaviour - even only on privacy grounds [but these are not even the primary grounds - I'm more worried about spam].  See http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1993/0028/latest/DLM296639.html Principle 4(b)(ii), Principle 5(a)(ii) and 5(a)(iii)  and Part 9a for relevant NZ law.  Australia has a similar act - https://www.comlaw.gov.au/Details/C2015C00598/Html/Text#_Toc437527218 part VIA from a quick reading, and I am pretty sure a lot of European countries have similar legislation.

Comment: Actually, on a closer reading of RFC1894 I take back most of what I said - this is low level stuff which talks about message delivery failures in a way which allows for catching of errors, rather then any kind of confirmation that the email has actually been delivered to a mailbox (let alone a read-receipt)

Comment: Hmm, if the final SMTP server also gets a DSN request, I'm sure that should also cover delivery to the MDA... and if not, then most mail servers in practice do at least report about _failed_ deliveries. (Of course, if it gets delivered to the "Spam" folder, it's still a successful delivery. But if the MDA couldn't store the message, that pretty much always causes a report...)

Comment: Not at all, many mail servers I'm aware of will silently accept clear cases spam and drop it - no notifications of any sort - ie it doesn't even get delivered to a spam folder - and indeed if people are using POP,  I can't see how a spam folder would even be useful to them !

Comment: As for legislation, at least Australia [does have delivery receipts](http://auspost.com.au/parcels-mail/registered-post.html)

Comment: Agreed, physical email does offer delivery receipts (not read / parcel opening receipts) .  I would also opine that this is to facilitate legal processes, and at a cost, and, crucially, between 2 parties with a presumed legitimate reason to be communicating with each other - which is very different to a spammer going on a fishing expedition - which would be a common use (and I fear that what the OP is doing may be very akin to spamming)

Answer (score 0):

If you've already sent the message, you can't really know, until the recipient actually sends a reply. There is no way to peek into someone's inbox like that.

Email does have delivery receipts & read receipts, but they must be requested when sending the message, not after. (Plus, not all mail apps support requesting them – e.g. Outlook has this option, as does Thunderbird, but Gmail doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not unreasonable to put your logo in the email and you can use the access to that rather than a suspicious looking 1 pixel extra payload

At the server side you need to perform a server redirect (eg via web.config on windows) so the request goes to your server application - just use something different for the url of the logo such as the email id in each email sent.

That way there is nothing abnormal at all to be seen at the client - but there are still issues

if the image is opened by an anti-abuse application looking perhaps for indecent images, then you are going to get a premature read report.  If the anti spam software gets canny, it will pattern match out the signature in the email.

So you can up the odds of you knowing but never really know 100%